# How to pass a URL parameter to a ObjectDataSource SelectMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a small example application with articles and comments.
Users can view a specific Article by passing the article ID value in URL:

```
http://localhost:56079/viewArticle.aspx?id=123456
```

I want the Article id to be used to find corresponding comments and populate a gridview with them in the same form.

viewArticle.aspx:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  FieldName="field1"   Caption="Field #1"      VisibleIndex="0" />
                    <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  FieldName="field2"   Caption="Field #2" VisibleIndex="1" />
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
                SelectMethod="searchComments"
                TypeName="App.CommentManager">
                <SelectParameters>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

If **id** is "hard-coded" in the searchComments method, gridview is populated with correct entries.

My only problem is passing the article **id** to searchComments method.

- I was thinking about a <%# %>" style databinding approach, but it would be extremely dirty, and it still doesn't work.

  ```
  SelectMethod="searchComments(<%# Request.QueryString["id"] %>)"
  ```
- Another approach I tried was setting the selectmethod in codebehind like this:

  ```
  ObjectDataSource1.SelectMethod = "searchComments('123456')";
  ```

  That results in error: ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'searchComments('123456')' that has no parameters.

Comment: My suggestion: don't use dataSources on aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a QueryStringParameter directly into SelectParameters - ie:

```
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter  QueryStringField="id" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QueryStringParameter` in `SelectParameters` section

```
    <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="id" Name="id"/>
    </SelectParameters>
```